# sparklyr can't see databases created in Hive and vice versa

Tags: r, hadoop, hive, sparklyr

I installed Apache Hive in local and I was trying to read tables via Rstudio/sparklyr.

I created a database using Hive:

```
hive> CREATE DATABASE test;
```

and I was trying to read that database using the following R script:

```
library(sparklyr)
library(dplyr)
library(DBI)

spark_disconnect_all()

Sys.setenv(SPARK_HOME = "/home/alessandro/spark-2.1.0-bin-hadoop2.7")

config <- spark_config()
config$spark.executor.instances <- 4
config$spark.executor.cores <- 4
config$spark.executor.memory <- "4G"
config$spark.sql.hive.metastore <- "/home/alessandro/spark-warehouse"
config$hive.metastore.warehouse.dir <- "/home/alessandro/spark-warehouse"
sc <- spark_connect(master="local", config=config, version="2.1.0")

dbGetQuery(sc, "show databases")
```

Still, `dbGetQuery(sc, "show databases")` does not show the database created, and that's awkward since the database folder test.db is correctly placed in the specified `hive.metastore.warehouse.dir`.

Similarly, if I create a database using dbGetQuery(sc, "CREATE DATABASE test2"), a database folder is created in `hive.metastore.warehouse.dir`, but I can't see it via Hive using:

```
hive> show databases;
```

Basically, even if all the database folders are placed in the correct path, from Hive I can see only databases created via Hive, whereas from R I can see only databases created via R.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved the issue adding in the file hive-site.xml the configuration to connect with hive:

```
   <property>
    <name>hive.metastore.uris</name>
    <value>thrift://localhost:9083</value>
  </property>
```