# Hive tables not showing in Spark session

Tags: r, apache-spark, hive, sparklyr

If I run `DBI::dbGetQuery(sc, "SHOW DATABASES")` in R, I get as result only `default` database.
And not the full list of hive tables created from the `hive>` command line...

[Also in the R project dir, get's created a derby.log and metastore_db folder.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VDaBr.png)

So my guess is that sparklyr's spark session is no using the global hive config...

I'm using Spark 3.3.0, Sparklyr 1.7.8 and MySQL for metastore...

I have tried changing `sql.warehouse.dir` to the value of hive's `hive.metastore.warehouse.dir` which is `"/user/hive/warehouse"` and `sql.catalogImplementation` to `"hive"`.

```
options(sparklyr.log.console = TRUE)

sc_config <- spark_config()
sc_config$spark.sql.warehouse.dir <- "/user/hive/warehouse"
sc_config$spark.sql.catalogImplementation <- "hive"
sc <- spark_connect(master = "yarn", spark_home = "/home/ml/spark", app_name = "TestAPP", config = sc_config)
sparklyr::hive_context_config(sc)
```

This is the log from `> sparklyr.log.console = TRUE`:

```
22/10/18 11:11:43 INFO sparklyr: Session (97754) is starting under 127.0.0.1 port 8880
22/10/18 11:11:43 INFO sparklyr: Session (97754) found port 8880 is available
22/10/18 11:11:43 INFO sparklyr: Gateway (97754) is waiting for sparklyr client to connect to port 8880
22/10/18 11:11:43 INFO sparklyr: Gateway (97754) accepted connection
22/10/18 11:11:43 INFO sparklyr: Gateway (97754) is waiting for sparklyr client to connect to port 8880
22/10/18 11:11:43 INFO sparklyr: Gateway (97754) received command 0
22/10/18 11:11:43 INFO sparklyr: Gateway (97754) found requested session matches current session
22/10/18 11:11:43 INFO sparklyr: Gateway (97754) is creating backend and allocating system resources
22/10/18 11:11:43 INFO sparklyr: Gateway (97754) is using port 8881 for backend channel
22/10/18 11:11:44 INFO sparklyr: Gateway (97754) created the backend
22/10/18 11:11:44 INFO sparklyr: Gateway (97754) is waiting for R process to end
22/10/18 11:11:46 INFO HiveConf: Found configuration file null
22/10/18 11:11:46 INFO SparkContext: Running Spark version 3.3.0
22/10/18 11:11:46 WARN NativeCodeLoader: Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform... using builtin-java classes where applicable
22/10/18 11:11:47 INFO ResourceUtils: ==============================================================
22/10/18 11:11:47 INFO ResourceUtils: No custom resources configured for spark.driver.
22/10/18 11:11:47 INFO ResourceUtils: ==============================================================
22/10/18 11:11:47 INFO SparkContext: Submitted application: TestAPP
22/10/18 11:11:47 INFO ResourceProfile: Default ResourceProfile created, executor resources: Map(cores -> name: cores, amount: 1, script: , vendor: , memory -> name: memory, amount: 512, script: , vendor: , offHeap -> name: offHeap, amount: 0, script: , vendor: ), task resources: Map(cpus -> name: cpus, amount: 1.0)
22/10/18 11:11:47 INFO ResourceProfile: Limiting resource is cpus at 1 tasks per executor
22/10/18 11:11:47 INFO ResourceProfileManager: Added ResourceProfile id: 0
22/10/18 11:11:48 INFO SecurityManager: Changing view acls to: ml
22/10/18 11:11:48 INFO SecurityManager: Changing modify acls to: ml
22/10/18 11:11:48 INFO SecurityManager: Changing view acls groups to: 
22/10/18 11:11:48 INFO SecurityManager: Changing modify acls groups to: 
22/10/18 11:11:48 INFO SecurityManager: SecurityManager: authentication disabled; ui acls disabled; users  with view permissions: Set(ml); groups with view permissions: Set(); users  with modify permissions: Set(ml); groups with modify permissions: Set()
22/10/18 11:11:48 INFO Utils: Successfully started service 'sparkDriver' on port 38889.
22/10/18 11:11:48 INFO SparkEnv: Registering MapOutputTracker
22/10/18 11:11:48 INFO SparkEnv: Registering BlockManagerMaster
22/10/18 11:11:48 INFO BlockManagerMasterEndpoint: Using org.apache.spark.storage.DefaultTopologyMapper for getting topology information
22/10/18 11:11:48 INFO BlockManagerMasterEndpoint: BlockManagerMasterEndpoint up
22/10/18 11:11:48 INFO SparkEnv: Registering BlockManagerMasterHeartbeat
22/10/18 11:11:49 INFO DiskBlockManager: Created local directory at /tmp/blockmgr-65ec8b4e-6131-4fed-a227-ea5b2162e4d8
22/10/18 11:11:49 INFO MemoryStore: MemoryStore started with capacity 93.3 MiB
22/10/18 11:11:49 INFO SparkEnv: Registering OutputCommitCoordinator
22/10/18 11:11:50 INFO Utils: Successfully started service 'SparkUI' on port 4040.
22/10/18 11:11:50 INFO SparkContext: Added JAR file:/home/ml/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/4.2/sparklyr/java/sparklyr-master-2.12.jar at spark://master:38889/jars/sparklyr-master-2.12.jar with timestamp 1666116706621
22/10/18 11:11:51 INFO DefaultNoHARMFailoverProxyProvider: Connecting to ResourceManager at /0.0.0.0:8032
22/10/18 11:11:53 INFO Configuration: resource-types.xml not found
22/10/18 11:11:53 INFO ResourceUtils: Unable to find 'resource-types.xml'.
22/10/18 11:11:53 INFO Client: Verifying our application has not requested more than the maximum memory capability of the cluster (8192 MB per container)
22/10/18 11:11:53 INFO Client: Will allocate AM container, with 896 MB memory including 384 MB overhead
22/10/18 11:11:53 INFO Client: Setting up container launch context for our AM
22/10/18 11:11:53 INFO Client: Setting up the launch environment for our AM container
22/10/18 11:11:53 INFO Client: Preparing resources for our AM container
22/10/18 11:11:53 WARN Client: Neither spark.yarn.jars nor spark.yarn.archive is set, falling back to uploading libraries under SPARK_HOME.
22/10/18 11:12:03 INFO Client: Uploading resource file:/tmp/spark-71575ad6-a8f7-43c0-974e-7c751281ef51/__spark_libs__890394313143327111.zip -> file:/home/ml/.sparkStaging/application_1665674177007_0028/__spark_libs__890394313143327111.zip
22/10/18 11:12:07 INFO Client: Uploading resource file:/tmp/spark-71575ad6-a8f7-43c0-974e-7c751281ef51/__spark_conf__9152665720324853254.zip -> file:/home/ml/.sparkStaging/application_1665674177007_0028/__spark_conf__.zip
22/10/18 11:12:08 INFO SecurityManager: Changing view acls to: ml
22/10/18 11:12:08 INFO SecurityManager: Changing modify acls to: ml
22/10/18 11:12:08 INFO SecurityManager: Changing view acls groups to: 
22/10/18 11:12:08 INFO SecurityManager: Changing modify acls groups to: 
22/10/18 11:12:08 INFO SecurityManager: SecurityManager: authentication disabled; ui acls disabled; users  with view permissions: Set(ml); groups with view permissions: Set(); users  with modify permissions: Set(ml); groups with modify permissions: Set()
22/10/18 11:12:08 INFO Client: Submitting application application_1665674177007_0028 to ResourceManager
22/10/18 11:12:08 INFO YarnClientImpl: Submitted application application_1665674177007_0028
22/10/18 11:12:09 INFO Client: Application report for application_1665674177007_0028 (state: ACCEPTED)
22/10/18 11:12:09 INFO Client: 
     client token: N/A
     diagnostics: [Tue Oct 18 11:12:08 -0700 2022] Application is Activated, waiting for resources to be assigned for AM.  Details : AM Partition = <DEFAULT_PARTITION> ; Partition Resource = <memory:16384, vCores:16> ; Queue's Absolute capacity = 100.0 % ; Queue's Absolute used capacity = 0.0 % ; Queue's Absolute max capacity = 100.0 % ; Queue's capacity (absolute resource) = <memory:16384, vCores:16> ; Queue's used capacity (absolute resource) = <memory:0, vCores:0> ; Queue's max capacity (absolute resource) = <memory:16384, vCores:16> ; 
     ApplicationMaster host: N/A
     ApplicationMaster RPC port: -1
     queue: default
     start time: 1666116728172
     final status: UNDEFINED
     tracking URL: http://master:8088/proxy/application_1665674177007_0028/
     user: ml
22/10/18 11:12:10 INFO Client: Application report for application_1665674177007_0028 (state: ACCEPTED)
22/10/18 11:12:11 INFO Client: Application report for application_1665674177007_0028 (state: ACCEPTED)
22/10/18 11:12:12 INFO Client: Application report for application_1665674177007_0028 (state: ACCEPTED)
22/10/18 11:12:13 INFO Client: Application report for application_1665674177007_0028 (state: ACCEPTED)
22/10/18 11:12:14 INFO Client: Application report for application_1665674177007_0028 (state: ACCEPTED)
22/10/18 11:12:15 INFO Client: Application report for application_1665674177007_0028 (state: ACCEPTED)
22/10/18 11:12:16 INFO Client: Application report for application_1665674177007_0028 (state: ACCEPTED)
22/10/18 11:12:17 INFO Client: Application report for application_1665674177007_0028 (state: ACCEPTED)
22/10/18 11:12:18 INFO Client: Application report for application_1665674177007_0028 (state: ACCEPTED)
22/10/18 11:12:19 INFO Client: Application report for application_1665674177007_0028 (state: ACCEPTED)
22/10/18 11:12:20 INFO Client: Application report for application_1665674177007_0028 (state: ACCEPTED)
22/10/18 11:12:21 INFO Client: Application report for application_1665674177007_0028 (state: ACCEPTED)
22/10/18 11:12:22 INFO Client: Application report for application_1665674177007_0028 (state: ACCEPTED)
22/10/18 11:12:23 INFO Client: Application report for application_1665674177007_0028 (state: RUNNING)
22/10/18 11:12:23 INFO Client: 
     client token: N/A
     diagnostics: N/A
     ApplicationMaster host: 192.168.1.82
     ApplicationMaster RPC port: -1
     queue: default
     start time: 1666116728172
     final status: UNDEFINED
     tracking URL: http://master:8088/proxy/application_1665674177007_0028/
     user: ml
22/10/18 11:12:23 INFO YarnClientSchedulerBackend: Application application_1665674177007_0028 has started running.
22/10/18 11:12:23 INFO Utils: Successfully started service 'org.apache.spark.network.netty.NettyBlockTransferService' on port 43035.
22/10/18 11:12:23 INFO NettyBlockTransferService: Server created on master:43035
22/10/18 11:12:23 INFO BlockManager: Using org.apache.spark.storage.RandomBlockReplicationPolicy for block replication policy
22/10/18 11:12:23 INFO BlockManagerMaster: Registering BlockManager BlockManagerId(driver, master, 43035, None)
22/10/18 11:12:23 INFO BlockManagerMasterEndpoint: Registering block manager master:43035 with 93.3 MiB RAM, BlockManagerId(driver, master, 43035, None)
22/10/18 11:12:23 INFO BlockManagerMaster: Registered BlockManager BlockManagerId(driver, master, 43035, None)
22/10/18 11:12:23 INFO BlockManager: Initialized BlockManager: BlockManagerId(driver, master, 43035, None)
22/10/18 11:12:23 INFO YarnClientSchedulerBackend: Add WebUI Filter. org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.webproxy.amfilter.AmIpFilter, Map(PROXY_HOSTS -> master, PROXY_URI_BASES -> http://master:8088/proxy/application_1665674177007_0028), /proxy/application_1665674177007_0028
22/10/18 11:12:24 INFO ServerInfo: Adding filter to /jobs: org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.webproxy.amfilter.AmIpFilter
22/10/18 11:12:24 INFO ServerInfo: Adding filter to /jobs/json: org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.webproxy.amfilter.AmIpFilter
22/10/18 11:12:24 INFO ServerInfo: Adding filter to /jobs/job: org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.webproxy.amfilter.AmIpFilter
22/10/18 11:12:24 INFO ServerInfo: Adding filter to /jobs/job/json: org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.webproxy.amfilter.AmIpFilter
22/10/18 11:12:24 INFO ServerInfo: Adding filter to /stages: org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.webproxy.amfilter.AmIpFilter
22/10/18 11:12:24 INFO ServerInfo: Adding filter to /stages/json: org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.webproxy.amfilter.AmIpFilter
22/10/18 11:12:24 INFO ServerInfo: Adding filter to /stages/stage: org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.webproxy.amfilter.AmIpFilter
22/10/18 11:12:24 INFO ServerInfo: Adding filter to /stages/stage/json: org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.webproxy.amfilter.AmIpFilter
22/10/18 11:12:24 INFO ServerInfo: Adding filter to /stages/pool: org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.webproxy.amfilter.AmIpFilter
22/10/18 11:12:24 INFO ServerInfo: Adding filter to /stages/pool/json: org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.webproxy.amfilter.AmIpFilter
22/10/18 11:12:24 INFO ServerInfo: Adding filter to /storage: org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.webproxy.amfilter.AmIpFilter
22/10/18 11:12:24 INFO ServerInfo: Adding filter to /storage/json: org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.webproxy.amfilter.AmIpFilter
22/10/18 11:12:24 INFO ServerInfo: Adding filter to /storage/rdd: org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.webproxy.amfilter.AmIpFilter
22/10/18 11:12:24 INFO ServerInfo: Adding filter to /storage/rdd/json: org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.webproxy.amfilter.AmIpFilter
22/10/18 11:12:24 INFO ServerInfo: Adding filter to /environment: org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.webproxy.amfilter.AmIpFilter
22/10/18 11:12:24 INFO ServerInfo: Adding filter to /environment/json: org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.webproxy.amfilter.AmIpFilter
22/10/18 11:12:24 INFO ServerInfo: Adding filter to /executors: org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.webproxy.amfilter.AmIpFilter
22/10/18 11:12:24 INFO ServerInfo: Adding filter to /executors/json: org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.webproxy.amfilter.AmIpFilter
22/10/18 11:12:24 INFO ServerInfo: Adding filter to /executors/threadDump: org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.webproxy.amfilter.AmIpFilter
22/10/18 11:12:24 INFO ServerInfo: Adding filter to /executors/threadDump/json: org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.webproxy.amfilter.AmIpFilter
22/10/18 11:12:24 INFO ServerInfo: Adding filter to /static: org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.webproxy.amfilter.AmIpFilter
22/10/18 11:12:25 INFO ServerInfo: Adding filter to /: org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.webproxy.amfilter.AmIpFilter
22/10/18 11:12:25 INFO ServerInfo: Adding filter to /api: org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.webproxy.amfilter.AmIpFilter
22/10/18 11:12:25 INFO ServerInfo: Adding filter to /jobs/job/kill: org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.webproxy.amfilter.AmIpFilter
22/10/18 11:12:25 INFO ServerInfo: Adding filter to /stages/stage/kill: org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.webproxy.amfilter.AmIpFilter
22/10/18 11:12:25 INFO ServerInfo: Adding filter to /metrics/json: org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.webproxy.amfilter.AmIpFilter
22/10/18 11:12:25 INFO YarnClientSchedulerBackend: SchedulerBackend is ready for scheduling beginning after waiting maxRegisteredResourcesWaitingTime: 30000000000(ns)
22/10/18 11:12:25 INFO SharedState: Setting hive.metastore.warehouse.dir ('null') to the value of spark.sql.warehouse.dir.
22/10/18 11:12:25 INFO SharedState: Warehouse path is 'file:/user/hive/warehouse'.
22/10/18 11:12:25 INFO ServerInfo: Adding filter to /SQL: org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.webproxy.amfilter.AmIpFilter
22/10/18 11:12:25 INFO ServerInfo: Adding filter to /SQL/json: org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.webproxy.amfilter.AmIpFilter
22/10/18 11:12:25 INFO ServerInfo: Adding filter to /SQL/execution: org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.webproxy.amfilter.AmIpFilter
22/10/18 11:12:25 INFO ServerInfo: Adding filter to /SQL/execution/json: org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.webproxy.amfilter.AmIpFilter
22/10/18 11:12:25 INFO ServerInfo: Adding filter to /static/sql: org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.webproxy.amfilter.AmIpFilter
22/10/18 11:12:25 INFO YarnSchedulerBackend$YarnSchedulerEndpoint: ApplicationMaster registered as NettyRpcEndpointRef(spark-client://YarnAM)
22/10/18 11:12:29 WARN YarnSchedulerBackend$YarnSchedulerEndpoint: Requesting driver to remove executor 1 for reason Container from a bad node: container_1665674177007_0028_02_000002 on host: worker1. Exit status: -1000. Diagnostics: [2022-10-18 11:12:26.949]File file:/home/ml/.sparkStaging/application_1665674177007_0028/__spark_libs__890394313143327111.zip does not exist
java.io.FileNotFoundException: File file:/home/ml/.sparkStaging/application_1665674177007_0028/__spark_libs__890394313143327111.zip does not exist
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.RawLocalFileSystem.deprecatedGetFileStatus(RawLocalFileSystem.java:779)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.RawLocalFileSystem.getFileLinkStatusInternal(RawLocalFileSystem.java:1100)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.RawLocalFileSystem.getFileStatus(RawLocalFileSystem.java:769)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FilterFileSystem.getFileStatus(FilterFileSystem.java:462)
    at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.util.FSDownload.verifyAndCopy(FSDownload.java:271)
    at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.util.FSDownload.access$000(FSDownload.java:68)
    at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.util.FSDownload$2.run(FSDownload.java:415)
    at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.util.FSDownload$2.run(FSDownload.java:412)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:422)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1878)
    at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.util.FSDownload.call(FSDownload.java:412)
    at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.containermanager.localizer.ContainerLocalizer$FSDownloadWrapper.doDownloadCall(ContainerLocalizer.java:247)
    at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.containermanager.localizer.ContainerLocalizer$FSDownloadWrapper.call(ContainerLocalizer.java:240)
    at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.containermanager.localizer.ContainerLocalizer$FSDownloadWrapper.call(ContainerLocalizer.java:228)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:750)

.
22/10/18 11:12:29 INFO BlockManagerMaster: Removal of executor 1 requested
22/10/18 11:12:29 INFO YarnSchedulerBackend$YarnDriverEndpoint: Asked to remove non-existent executor 1
22/10/18 11:12:29 INFO BlockManagerMasterEndpoint: Trying to remove executor 1 from BlockManagerMaster.
22/10/18 11:12:39 INFO HiveUtils: Initializing HiveMetastoreConnection version 2.3.9 using Spark classes.
22/10/18 11:12:40 INFO HiveClientImpl: Warehouse location for Hive client (version 2.3.9) is file:/user/hive/warehouse
22/10/18 11:12:41 INFO YarnSchedulerBackend$YarnDriverEndpoint: Registered executor NettyRpcEndpointRef(spark-client://Executor) (192.168.1.82:43560) with ID 2,  ResourceProfileId 0
22/10/18 11:12:42 INFO BlockManagerMasterEndpoint: Registering block manager master:40397 with 93.3 MiB RAM, BlockManagerId(2, master, 40397, None)
22/10/18 11:12:49 INFO YarnSchedulerBackend$YarnDriverEndpoint: Registered executor NettyRpcEndpointRef(spark-client://Executor) (192.168.1.82:43600) with ID 3,  ResourceProfileId 0
22/10/18 11:12:50 INFO BlockManagerMasterEndpoint: Registering block manager master:44035 with 93.3 MiB RAM, BlockManagerId(3, master, 44035, None)
```

And this is the print from `> sparklyr::hive_context_config(sc)`: https://pastebin.com/e28KJ4wQ

Any help?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Also If I copy `hive-site.xml` file to `$HOME_SPARK/conf/` I get this errors:
`ERROR sparklyr: Gateway (72840) failed calling sql on 10: org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.HiveException: java.lang.RuntimeException[...]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay so I found the solution on [this other question.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44279875/sparklyr-cant-see-databases-created-in-hive-and-vice-versa)

I added this property to my `hive-site.xml` and also copied it to `$HOME_SPARK/conf/`

```
<property>
    <name>hive.metastore.uris</name>
    <value>thrift://localhost:9083</value>
  </property>
```

Also I removed all `spark_config()` configs that I tried before.

*I would love to know why was this the solution.*

Answer (score 0):

When the spark session is created, you could get configure "spark.sql.catalogImplementation" to see if it is "hive".

If spark can not find the hive class, it will change the config to "in-memory".

In org.apache.spark.repl.Main:

```
if (conf.get(CATALOG_IMPLEMENTATION.key, "hive").toLowerCase(Locale.ROOT) == "hive") {
      if (SparkSession.hiveClassesArePresent) {
        // In the case that the property is not set at all, builder's config
        // does not have this value set to 'hive' yet. The original default
        // behavior is that when there are hive classes, we use hive catalog.
        sparkSession = builder.enableHiveSupport().getOrCreate()
        logInfo("Created Spark session with Hive support")
      } else {
        // Need to change it back to 'in-memory' if no hive classes are found
        // in the case that the property is set to hive in spark-defaults.conf
        builder.config(CATALOG_IMPLEMENTATION.key, "in-memory")
        sparkSession = builder.getOrCreate()
        logInfo("Created Spark session")
      }
    } else {
      // In the case that the property is set but not to 'hive', the internal
      // default is 'in-memory'. So the sparkSession will use in-memory catalog.
      sparkSession = builder.getOrCreate()
      logInfo("Created Spark session")
    }
```